# A question regarding Functions grade 11 sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions

> A sequence is defined by $$t_n=\begin{cases} -3& \text{if}\ n=4k\\ 2 & \text{if}\ n=4k+1\\ 5 & \text{if}\ n=4k+2\\ -1 & \text{if}\ n=4k+3\end{cases} \text{for}\ k=0,1,2,3,\ldots$$
>   Determine $t_{345}$.

Would greatly appreciate any level of aid.

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: Hint: write the first few terms and find a pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You have to find out what is the remainder of $345$ in dividing by $4$

If the remainder is $1$ then you have the case of $4k+1$ for the answer is $t_{345}=2$